# nginx pass through proxy not displaying UI properly

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a github server whose UI I can access directly just fine

[image]

Now I want to access the same instance but via a SSL passthrough proxy using nginx. My config is as simple as

```
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf 
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name github-proxy-test-int.web.company.com;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/github-proxy-test-int.web.company.com.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/website.com.key;
    
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://github-dev.web-dev.company.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

But when I access the proxy UI using `github-proxy-test-int.web.company.com`, I see the following

[image]

I just want to access the same UI and all the flows using the proxy. Any idea what Im missing ?

Doing an inspect on the page, Im getting

[image]

Comment: Check the developer tools to find out which resources it wants to access but fails. Maybe there are some hard coded URLs which don't pass through the reverse proxy. Note that a reverse proxy in front of the server is functionality very different from a client side proxy - the first one cares about the specific domain, the latter one about all traffic (any domain).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Also I just did an inspect on the page. Added the screenshot above

Comment: As you can see - it still tries to load resources from the non-proxied URL and fails to use these because of restrictions in the Content-Security-Policy. Thus your site behind the proxy is using absolut URLs in critical places. You would need to adjust the web application to use only relative URL. No idea if the application allows this and how it can be done.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks. I tried adding the following header to my nginx server configs `proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://github-proxy-test-int.web.company.com";` but unfortunately that didnt solve the issue. Ill have a look at the github server itself